# How to run own gTLD on my DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting, tld

My organization shelled out for a gTLD, and we currently use 3rd party (Verisign) to host it on their DNS servers. However, there are 2 issues: we pay quite a bit for that yearly (that's the lesser issue); updating data there is... convoluted (also for our organizational reasons).

However, we run quite huge DNS system for our other (non-TLD) domains. I have tried searching if it's possible to self-host gTLD, but while I found some info for *new* gTLDs, I haven't for transferring existing gTLDs.

Can anyone point me to some overview/howto/readme, or can just speak from experience?

EDIT: for sake of having a reference point, let's say I already own .example. gTLD. Currently it is maintained on Verisign DNS servers. I want to be able to maintain it on my own DNS servers.

Comment: Well, not really mixed, I know that those are 2 separate entities, however for me it's just 1 company. I want to move my domain to my own DNS (external-facing) server, and the domain is a gTLD.

Comment: I would suspect that https://www.iana.org/domains/root/manage is what you're looking for, but I have no personal experience with this.

Comment: @Håkan Same experience level here. I did stumble across the [applicant guidebook](https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/agb) for newgTLDs, but section 1.1.2.11 makes it pretty clear that the applicant has to demonstrate existence of a registry. I don't think it would be possible to directly delegate the entire newgTLD to a set of nameservers that are not part of a registry implementation.

Answer (score 24):

Håkan is basically correct. The approval process for your gTLD included extensive technical testing of the platform serving it, both for conformance to DNS specifications (both RFCs and gTLD-particular specs from ICANN), world-wide availability over both IPv4 and IPv6, performance of registry interfaces (EPP, that is) and more. Since you're using Verisign you may not have noticed that this happened, since their platform hosts a whole bunch of TLDs and is known to be good (in that regard, at least). If you are to move your gTLD to an entirely new platform, I suspect that ICANN will want that the testing be repeated. I strongly recommend that you contact ICANN directly and ask how to handle this.

[Note: I know these things because I was involved in building the technical testing platform for the current set of new gTLDs, and personally wrote most of the DNS standards conformance tests for it.]

Comment: So, I suspect, just saying "I have BIND running" is not enough :) But what are the technical reasons for such extensive testing of my own gTLD platform? In other words, who - other than myself - an I hurting if the platform is not robust enough?

Comment: You'd be hurting everyone you delegate domains in your TLD to, which could be millions of people. The rules were written with TLDs operating as traditional TLDs (like `.COM`) in mind. So it's overkill for a vanity TLD, yes, but there can't really be different rules for different applicants.

Answer (score 11):

I don't have personal experience with the operation of a *New gTLD* but the answer surely must be that it is possible for you to operate your own nameservers (and other services). I think the question rather is "at what cost", to which I do not have a direct answer.

IANA's [technical requirements for nameservers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements) appears to be a straightforward technical baseline, essentially just normal best practices for any domain. (You should obviously still review them.)

Making changes to a gTLD delegation also appears relatively straightforward, IANA has information on how to [manage a delegation](https://www.iana.org/domains/root/manage) readily available and a web-based management interface.

However, browsing through the [New gTLD Applicant Guidebook](https://newgtlds.icann.org/en/applicants/agb), it would appear that during the application process you provided IANA with documentation of how you will operate in compliance with their policies, a good chunk of which appears to be about the technical operation of the gTLD registry and nameserver services (presumably answered, at least to some extent, based on your use of these externally provided services which you now want to replace).
It seems that it would be prudent to review your own application and the agreements you entered with IANA to assess the impact of these planned changes when it comes to complying with policy and any additional technical requirements mandated therein.

Comment: +1 for that last sentence...